# BigDecimal failed to set precision of 8 digits during multiplication

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I am trying make a multiplication of a BigDecimal number with a precision of 8 digits

Here is what I want to take

```
0.02749639
```

This is my code

```
double amount = 2120;
double BuyPrice = 0.00001297;
BigDecimal result=BigDecimal.valueOf(BuyPrice).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount)).setScale(8,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
System.out.println(result);
```

and here what did I took

```
0.027496400
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: But 0.0274964 is the correct answer!

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem for me it is not the correct answer beacue the stock price of the market is 0.02749639 and no 0.0274964

Comment: Look, 2120 x 0.00001297 = 0.0274964 is a mathematical fact.  If you wish to redefine mathematics so that there's some different answer, you'll have to be more specific about how your "modified mathematics" should work.

Comment: I will downvote anyone who posts anything equivalent to `System.out.println((long)(2120 * 0.00001297 * 100000000 ) / 100000000.);` as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.0274964 is the right result. Perhaps in some other part of your code you have already lost precision due to using `double`?

When you use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` you are experiencing a precision loss when you declare the `double`. To avoid it one should use `new BigDecimal(String)` constructor:

```
BigDecimal d1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(90.000000000000001d);
BigDecimal d2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(90.000000000000002d);
System.out.println(d1.equals(d2));

BigDecimal s1 = new BigDecimal("90.000000000000001");
BigDecimal s2 = new BigDecimal("90.000000000000002");
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Will print

```
true
false
```

Comment: it is important to me to get this result 0.02749639 because it is a stock price. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: [It's not 0.02749639](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=0.00001297+*+2120&t=canonical&ia=calculator), you can't cheat math. Either modify the inputs to your problem or change the result to be correct.

Comment: Just calculate 2120 * 1297 (simple integers) and you get 2749640. So the result you got is correct and 0.2749639 is wrong.